# Using Ionic 7 and React 18, how do I access the history object to navigate between pages?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router, history

I'm using Ionic 7 and React 18.  I want to build a drop down component such that when an option is selected, my URL will change to include the ID of the selected option.  I have this set up in my App.tsx file,

```
<IonHeader>
  <IonToolbar>
    <IonButtons slot="start">
      <IonButton>
        <IonIcon icon={logoReact} />
      </IonButton>
    </IonButtons>
    <IonTitle>My Title</IonTitle>
    <IonButtons slot="end">
      <IonButton>
        <IonIcon icon={search} />
      </IonButton>
      <IonButton>
        <IonIcon icon={personCircle} />
      </IonButton>
    </IonButtons>
  </IonToolbar>
  <IonToolbar>
    <CategorySelectComponent />
  </IonToolbar>
</IonHeader>
...
   <IonReactRouter>
      <IonRouterOutlet>
        <Route exact path="/home">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Redirect to="/home" />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/cards/:categoryId">
          <CardSlideComponent />
        </Route>
      </IonRouterOutlet>
```

and my selection component is as such

```
import {
  IonContent,
  IonItem,
  IonLabel,
  IonPage,
  IonSelect,
  IonSelectOption,
} from "@ionic/react";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import CardService from "../services/CardService";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const CategorySelectComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState<string | undefined>(
    undefined
  );
  const [options, setOptions] = useState<Category[]>([]);

  const history = useHistory();
  console.log(history); // this is always undefined

  const handleSelectionChange = (event: CustomEvent) => {
    const selectedCategoryId = event.detail.value;
    setSelectedValue(selectedCategoryId);

    // Navigate to the selected category page
    console.log("handle change ...");
    console.log(history);
    history.push(`/cards/${selectedCategoryId}`);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    CardService.getCategories(setOptions);
  }, []); // Empty dependency array means this effect runs once on component mount

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonContent>
        <IonItem>
          <IonLabel>Choose an option:</IonLabel>
          <IonSelect
            value={selectedValue}
            onIonChange={handleSelectionChange}
            interface="popover"
          >
            {options.map((category) => (
              <IonSelectOption key={category.id} value={category.id}>
                {category.name}
              </IonSelectOption>
            ))}
          </IonSelect>
        </IonItem>

        <IonItem>
          <IonLabel>Selected Value:</IonLabel>
          <IonLabel>{selectedValue}</IonLabel>
        </IonItem>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
```

but the "history" component is consistently "undefined".  Is there a more "ionic" way of doing this that doesn't involve the history object?

Comment: I've always used the `useHistory` hook in my Ionic apps. Where exactly are you trying to use this hook in your app? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve]?

Comment: I've narrowed down the issue somewhat.  I edited my question to show where the component with the useHistory hook is located (it's in a header element in my App.tsx file).  I've noticed if I invoke the "useHistory" hook from a component within a "Route" element, it loads an actual object.  So maybe I need to find another way to reload my URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this same issue recently when needing to use the `useIonRouter` hook to check if back navigations were possible. You just need to promote the router component (*that provides the routing context, e.g. the `history` object*) higher in the ReactTree than any component consuming it.

Tuck the `IonHeader` component inside the `IonReactRouter` component so that `CategorySelectComponent` is rendered within its routing context.

```
<IonReactRouter>
  ...

  <IonHeader>
    <IonToolbar>
      <IonButtons slot="start">
        <IonButton>
          <IonIcon icon={logoReact} />
        </IonButton>
      </IonButtons>
      <IonTitle>My Title</IonTitle>
      <IonButtons slot="end">
        <IonButton>
          <IonIcon icon={search} />
        </IonButton>
        <IonButton>
          <IonIcon icon={personCircle} />
        </IonButton>
      </IonButtons>
    </IonToolbar>
    <IonToolbar>
      <CategorySelectComponent />
    </IonToolbar>
  </IonHeader>
  ...
   
  <IonRouterOutlet>
    <Route exact path="/home">
      <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/">
      <Redirect to="/home" />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/cards/:categoryId">
      <CardSlideComponent />
    </Route>
  </IonRouterOutlet>
</IonReactRouter>
```